# trying to create leader board and save locally to phone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game in unity and need a leader board that displays highscores and the name they provide at the end of the game.
How do I save these and keep them for later use (even after closing and reopening the game) and then apply them to a leaderboard.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the people who play are on different computers you'll need to persist the high score data on a machine somewhere.  (If they're not on different computers you could just store it in a text file locally on that single machine.)  A good choice for persisting would be a database.  You'll probably want to secure the database so that people don't mess with it so you may need a web or HTTP front-end that your Unity app interfaces with.  You can use [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) in Unity to call your front-end.